# Получить iframe карты по адресу через yandex maps api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps-api

Есть необходимость получить iframe карты по заданному адресу. 
У меня есть несколько полей: город, улица, дом. После заполнения последнего, адрес собирается в одну строку, и далее нужно сделать запрос к yandex maps api и получить iframe. 
Искал необходимое api/решение, не нашёл, поэтому вопрос:
Есть ли какой-то готовый способ или нужно собрать?

На всякий случай: фронт реализован на Vue.js 2 + Nuxt.js 3.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что этот функционал есть только в их непубличном API.

```http
https://yandex.ru/maps/api/shortenPath?ajax=1&csrfToken=abc:123&path=/?ll=37.620585%2C55.751461&mode=search&oid=1023322799&ol=biz&z=16.58&s=376169862&sessionId=xyz_456
```

```http
https://yandex.ru/maps/api/shortenPath?ajax=1&csrfToken=abc:123&path=/org/moskovskiy_kreml/1023322799/?ll=37.620585%2C55.751461&z=16&s=3624378469&sessionId=xyz_456
```

`ll` - это координаты
`path` - url места на maps.yandex.ru

В респонзе - JSON с короткой ссылкой на это место.
`{"data": "CCUfRFf9lC"}`

Код для iframe всегда одинаковый:

```html
<iframe
  src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/**ЗНАЧЕНИЕ_ИЗ_JSON**"
  width="560" height="400" frameborder="1"
  allowfullscreen="true"
  style="position:relative;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: получается, мне нужно сначала координаты получить, потом сделать второй запрос по вашему первому url, а после уже маунтить компонент?

Answer (score 0):

Использование непубличных методов нестабильно, поскольку может в любой момент быть закрыто. И при этом нарушает пользовательское соглашение, потому может быть закрыто персонально для вашего продукта. Не стоит так делать.

А вот схема генерации ссылки для открытия Яндекс Карты есть в их [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html). Причём геокодер для такого формата не потребуется. В [схеме поиска объекта](https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html#yandexmaps-web__search) можно прописать и адрес. В простейшем виде ссылка будет такой:

**[https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=Реутов,+Калинина,+20](https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2,+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0,+20)**

Её можно обернуть в айфрейм, чтобы получить его со стандартным интерфейсом. И это совершенно легальный метод.

```
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=Реутов, Калинина, 20" width="100%" height="400""></iframe>
```

Если хотите урезанного виджета, как по кнопке **Поделиться**, можно использовать чуть другой формат урла, взятый из кода виджета с поисковой строкой. Но гарантировать, что это будет работать вечно никто не может:

```
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?mode=search&text=Реутов, Калинина, 20" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="1" style="position:relative;"></iframe>
```